# Cannot await system collections generic ienumerable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await

I am very new to async programming and I have been asked to implement async without breaking the existing functionalities.
In my Web API Service Layer I have something like this :

```
public IList<Entities.Case.CreateCaseOutput> createCase(ARC.Donor.Data.Entities.Case.CreateCaseInput CreateCaseInput, ARC.Donor.Data.Entities.Case.SaveCaseSearchInput SaveCaseSearchInput)
{
    Repository rep = new Repository();
    string RequestType = "Insert";
    string strSPQuery = string.Empty;
    List<object> listParam = new List<object>();
    SQL.CaseSQL.getCreateCaseParameters(CreateCaseInput, RequestType, out strSPQuery, out listParam);
    var AcctLst = rep.ExecuteStoredProcedure<Entities.Case.CreateCaseOutput>(strSPQuery, listParam).ToList();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AcctLst.ElementAt(0).o_case_seq.ToString()))
        saveCaseSearch(SaveCaseSearchInput, AcctLst.ElementAt(0).o_case_seq);
    return AcctLst;
}
```

And this SaveCaseSearch is implemented asynchronously :

```
public async Task<IList<Entities.Case.SaveCaseSearchOutput>> saveCaseSearch(ARC.Donor.Data.Entities.Case.SaveCaseSearchInput SaveCaseSearchInput,Int64? case_key)
{
    Repository rep = new Repository();
    string strSPQuery = string.Empty;
    List<object> listParam = new List<object>();
    SQL.CaseSQL.getSaveCaseSearchParameters(SaveCaseSearchInput, case_key,out strSPQuery, out listParam);
    var AcctLst = await rep.ExecuteStoredProcedure<Entities.Case.SaveCaseSearchOutput>(strSPQuery, listParam).ToList();
    return AcctLst;
}
```

But it says :

[image]

ExecuteStoredProcedure looks like :

```
public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteStoredProcedure<T>(string strSPQuery, List<object> parameters)
{
    _msg = "";
    try
    {
        this._context.Database.CommandTimeout = 280;

        return this._context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(strSPQuery, parameters.ToArray());

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _msg = "ERROR: " + ex.Message;
        if (ex.InnerException != null) { _msg += "INNER EXCEPTION: " + ex.InnerException; }
        log.Info(_msg);
    }
    return null;
}
```

What can be done ? Is **ToListAsync()** something to look at ? When I tried it I got

[image]

and changing the ExecuteStoredProcedure definition produces

```
public Task<IEnumerable<T>> ExecuteStoredProcedure<T>(string strSPQuery, List<object> parameters)
{
    _msg = "";
    try
    {
        this._context.Database.CommandTimeout = 280;

        return this._context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(strSPQuery, parameters.ToArray());

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _msg = "ERROR: " + ex.Message;
        if (ex.InnerException != null) { _msg += "INNER EXCEPTION: " + ex.InnerException; }
        log.Info(_msg);
    }
    return null;
}
```

the error :

**Error 13  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' C:\Users\m1034699\Desktop\Stuart_V2_12042016\Stuart Web Service\ARC.Donor.Data\Repository.cs    115 24  ARC.Donor.Data**

I am not sure how to do that . Please help.

Comment: You only need to use `ToListAsync()` in the `System.Data.Entity` namespace. I'm not too sure what you're trying to do though, it seems like you have only one task and you don't even use the return value. Do you really need async code?

Comment: `ExecuteStoredProcedure<T>` must return `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`

Comment: I tried the same. But I got the attached error. :(

Comment: You can't use `await` in a method that *doesn't* return Task. `await` only *awaits* an already asynchronous method, it doesn't make it work asynchronously.

Comment: @StrugglingCoder You are using `ToListAsync()` on the return type of `ExeCuteStoredProcedure` which isn't a task so that can't work. You need to use async from the bottom to the top, including `ExecuteStoredProcedure`.

Comment: BTW this has already been answered: You need to use `ToListAsync` on *SqlQuery*, not the results of SqlQUery. This is available in the `System.Data.Entity` namespace

Comment: After changing the ExecuteStoredProcedure definition also , error remains. Please help with it.

Comment: What version of Entity Framework are you using? Asynchronous operations were added in EF 6. BTW the last error says that you tried to use the wrong return type. Please post the *actual* code that produced this error

Comment: @StrugglingCoder `return await this._context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(strSPQuery, parameters.ToArray()).ToListAsync();`

Comment: I have updated the question to include the modified ExecuteStoredProcedure definition. And this is the one I am getting the error for.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the Async version of the methods.

try:

```
var AcctLst = await rep.ExecuteStoredProcedure<Entities.Case.SaveCaseSearchOutput>(strSPQuery, listParam).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I don't know, sorry... But I would try to understand why you are trying to return a Task, but is not using async or await in the ExecuteStoredProcedure.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help Sir. So in that case async/await in ExecuteStoredProcedure only is suffiecient right ? I now have return await this._context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(strSPQuery, parameters.ToArray()).ToListAsync(); 

So in my service ToListAsync() is not further needed right ? Actually I am very new to this .. so sorry for guessing around.

Comment: You should use await if you are executing something that returns a Task<T>.if you dont use, your variable will store the task, no the T.